# Can't Install Gdebi

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, gdebi

Total newbie when it comes to Linux in general and Ubuntu in specific (literally installed it last night).

I'm having trouble installing software and read that GDebi would make it much easier. However, I can't even figure out how to install GDebi properly (it's a wonder I managed to install Opera!)

When I enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

I get

```
josiah@LAPTOP-JOSIAH-UBUNTU:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi<br>
[sudo] password for josiah: <br>
Reading package lists... Done<br>
Building dependency tree     <br>  
Reading state information... Done<br>
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:<br>
The following packages have unmet dependencies:<br>
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be<br> installed<br>
         Depends: gksu but it is not going to be installed<br>
         Depends: gnome-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed<br>
 gdebi-kde : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.3ubuntu2) but it is not going to<br> be installed<br>
             Depends: python3-pykde4 but it is not going to be installed<br>
             Depends: kdebase-runtime but it is not going to be installed or<br>
                      kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed or<br>
                      kdesudo but it is not going to be installed<br>
 megasync : Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not going to be installed<br>
            Depends: libcrypto++9v5 but it is not going to be installed<br>
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

So I tried

    apt-get -f install
```

But get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)<br>
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are y
```

Also tried installing via the Ubuntu Software Center, but get "waiting to install", which is the same problem that's causing me to install gdebi in the first place.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: This isn't an issue just wait a few minutes then try again other wise just reboot, then try again

Comment: Thanks so much, guys! The possible duplicate karel marked did the trick. Also appreciate the link from muru. Looking forward to learning more about the wide world of Ubuntu! Thanks again.